# Best practice arround using S3 as file storage for an application with database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, object-storage, file-storage

I think that using S3-compatible to do file storage for application assets or "attachments" is one of the most common use cases, but I see a couple of issues, which I am unclear on how to address.

If you are going to serve a fronted that can be cached or that is purely an HTML/JS project, it's clear that you could use the storage (+ CDN) to host it, but when storing files from the users I see that the options are:

1. Only the application has access to the bucket, and does a "pass-through" of the requested resource.
2. The application has written access, but read is public, meaning an application receives a resource and stores it to a bucket, and the client fetches a reference from the application to identify the resource on the bucket.
3. The application manages access, either by setting an OpenID type of model, or providing short-lived tokens to access a given object, and the client does everything with explicit permission from the application and by getting the correct reference to transact against.

I think the simple way is to use option number 2, I've seen FOSS project do that whenever they support S3-compatible storage.

But I am unsure on what could be good criteria to decide.

The main issue I see is that using approach 1, allows the application to be transparent to the client, while introducing a possible bottleneck when requesting multiple files.

And regarding number 3, sounds too sophisticated to implement in a POC.

Any thoughts or comments about what is the best practice regarding this scenario?

Answer (score 6):

Use approach #3.

You can use a [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides **time-limited access to private objects** in Amazon S3.

Basically:

- Objects are kept in a **private bucket**. Only the app can access the objects.
- When the app determines that a user is entitled to see a file, it **generates a pre-signed URL**. This can be done in a couple of lines of code and does not need an API call to AWS (it basically calculates a hash as a 'signature' to authorize the access).
- The user receives a link. When **clicked** or used, this sends a normal HTTP/S request to S3.
- S3 **verifies** that the signature is correct and the **expiry time** has not elapsed. If everything is good, the object is returned just like it would if the object was public.

Therefore, your app has responsibility for **authenticating** the users and determining which objects they are **entitled** to access. It **generates the pre-signed URL** and provides it to the user. The pre-signed URL can then be used as a link or even in `<img src="...">` references.

Comment: Would that be something that is exclusive to AWS or other providers would support similar approaches?

Comment: @ekiim a quick search will confirm that both GCS and Azure support signed URLs similar to AWS S3.

Comment: "Other providers" tend to produce S3-compatible APIs, so the same technique is available.